# NodeJS Module unable to return data from inside a closure

Tags: node.js

I am making trying to make a module that calls an API, using the following code:

```
var key = require('./keys').slack;
var unirest = require('unirest');

module.exports.apiCall = function() {
    var args = {"token": key, "channel": "C07RLKT6C", "text": "DebugmessagePlsIgnore", "as_user": true};

    var req = unirest.post("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");

    req.query(args).end(function(res) {
        // Output res
    });
}

console.log(this.apiCall());
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to output the result of res to return. I am using the Unirest module to request HTTPS data.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: @SLaks Sorry, but I don't understand the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a callback to manage that

```
var key = require('./keys').slack;
var unirest = require('unirest');

module.exports.apiCall = function(cb) {
    var args = {"token": key, "channel": "C07RLKT6C", "text": "DebugmessagePlsIgnore", "as_user": true};

    var req = unirest.post("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");

    req.query(args).end(function(res) {
        cb(null, res)
    });
}

this.apiCall(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: So in that case, all functions that use this would have to use the callback?
Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: You can use callbacks, promises, etc
I prefer Promises, you can find some tutorials online.

Comment: Ah. I'll look up promises.

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback.

```
//module.js

var key = require('./keys').slack;
var unirest = require('unirest');

module.exports.apiCall = function(callback) {
    var args = {"token": key, "channel": "C07RLKT6C", "text":  "DebugmessagePlsIgnore", "as_user": true};

    var req = unirest.post("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");

    req.query(args).end(callback);
}

// another file
var apiCall = require('./module');

apiCall(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but since DevAlien has answered it previously, I will select his answer as the accepted one, but I will upvote yours.

Comment: Ok. Think his might be wrong. Don't you want to use the function outside the module?

Comment: I have tried it outside the module, his seems to work (but I have to remove the "this." from apiCall).